# Simple exercise in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, problem-solving

Problem:
Prove the identity $V=\sum V[x_i]U_i$, where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are the natural coordinate functions. (Hint: evaluate $V=\sum v_i U_i $ on $x_j$)

Elementary differential geometry written by Barrett O'neill 1.3-4, p.15

I just don't know what the right term means. I just know that it is a linear combination of $V[x_i]$, a function from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$, and $U_i$, a natural frame field. What is the definition or meaning of $V[x_i]$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $V$ is avector in $\mathbb R^3$ then you can write it as a linear combination of the basis of $\mathbb R^3$ i.e. $V=(V.U_1)U_1+(V.U_2)U_2+(V.U_3)U_3$ but $V.U_1=(V_1,V_2,V_3).(1,0,0)=V_1$ in the same way  $V.U_2=V_2$ and $V.U_3=V_3$ $\implies V=V_1U_1+V_2U_2+V_3U_3$
on the other hand $V[x_i]=\sum_{j=1}^{3}V_j\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} $ where $i\in \{1,2,3\}\implies V[x_i]=\sum_{j=1}^{3}V_j\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}=V_i\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_i}=V_i$ thus $V[x_i]=V_i$ and so we get the identity .